# How can I route HTTP requests through a python script?

Tags: python, apache, http, static-pages

I've thoroughly searched for the answer for my question, but I don't think I know the correct terminology to make my searches effective. Anyway, I'm looking to set up my web server to route a request for a static page through a Python "PageBuilder" program which will dynamically implant content into templates.

In other words:

- user requests mysite.com/index.html
- server passes request to certain python script (my server is currently Apache2)
- python script generates output, passes output to server
- server serves content to user

Could someone please help me or at least give me the "proper terminology" with which to search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really static content any more. You want to dynamically generate content using a script.

In Python, this is generally done using the [WSGI interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) (in olden days, the de facto standard was [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)), which defines a standard way for your Python code to get input (information about the HTTP request), and send back a response (HTTP headers, and the content you want to serve -- typically HTML).

To this end, there's the excellent [`mod_wsgi` Apache module](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6) that sets up the plumbing between the server-stuff (receiving requests and sending back content) and your code, using this WSGI interface.

You may also want to check out some sort of [templating engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98245/what-is-your-single-favorite-python-templating-engine) to make generating dynamic HTML easier (my favourite is [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)).

Comment: Thanks, and I just wrote my own custom template engine over the last couple of days. :)

Answer (score -2):

This is called CGI.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: Don't use CGI. It's pretty slow. Today, there is WSGI.